# adding ns1 prefix to Jax ws

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I have a jax ws application with

```
WebService(name = "partner", targetNamespace = "http://com.myname.ws")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)

public interface Ipartner {
    @WebMethod

    public abstract WalletTransferResponse AccountToWalletTransfer(@WebParam(name = "a")int a);
}

@WebService(endpointInterface="com.ietech.interfaces.Ipartner",
        portName="partnerPort", serviceName = "partner")

public class partner implements Ipartner {
 @Override
    public WalletTransferResponse WalletTransfer(@WebParam(name = "a")int a) {

}
}
```

my request is

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://com.myname.ws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <com:WalletTransfer>
         <MobileTransferRequest>
```

and my response is

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns3:WalletTransferResponse xmlns:ns2="http://my.ws" xmlns:ns3="http://com.myname.ws">
         <return>
```

for my response how do i have ns1 as the prefix at against com? and for my response how do i have the same namespace prefix ns1 at against ns3, which i have now, and i dont know where ns2 and ns3 namespace is coming from, because i dont have such.

for my request this is what i need

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://com.myname.ws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:WalletTransfer>
         <MobileTransferRequest>
```

and response

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://com.myname.ws">
   <S:Body>
      <ns1:WalletTransferResponse>
         <return>
```